# How to add HTML5 features to my browser

Tags: html, browser, browser-support

What are the new features in HTML5? I want to try it, but my browser does not support it. I am using Windows XP with IE8. How do I work with this?

Comment: best for development Mozilla firefox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are forced to use IE8, you can get a lot of the features of Chrome by embedding it *in* your Internet Explorer browser using ChromeFrame

http://code.google.com/chrome/chromeframe/

You'd have to do this for each site/page you are developing but if you're forced to stay on IE8 its your only real option.

Answer (score 1):

Download Google Chrome, it's fast, easy and more secure than IE8. Also, it works with HTML5 and follows the web standards, unlike Internet Explorer.

http://www.google.com/chrome

Comment: can't i work with IE8.? if it is possible how can i ?

Comment: @mdhar9e: No, IE 8 doesn’t support any HTML5 features. IE 9 does, but that’s not available for Windows XP.

Comment: @Paul - contenteditable?

Comment: @Alohci: ah, yeah fair point.